# Null Pointer Exception for an array of Linked Lists

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

As I am trying to make an array of Linked Lists, I keep getting a NullPointerException. The linked list works on its own until I make an array of it.

```
MyLinkedList<String>[] list = new MyLinkedList[1];

list[0].addFirst("Milo");

System.out.println(list[0].get(0));
```

I keep getting this.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize each linked list inside the array, in *addition* to initializing the array itself, e.g.

```
MyLinkedList<String>[] list = new MyLinkedList[1];
list[0] = new MyLinkedList();
list[0].addFirst("Milo");
System.out.println(list[0].get(0));
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that arrays and generics don't mix well: use one or the other.